# cannot install nvidia drivers 340

Tags: drivers, nvidia, nvidia-geforce

I want to replace the default driver with Ubuntu notebook driver Nvidia 720m with the driver code 340. I tried it but failed to install:

```
> sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-340 : Depends: dkms but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: nvidia-settings (>= 331.20) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Ubuntu release? Anyway, according to Nvidia, the driver for your card is 418. The one you're trying to install is only for legacy hardware.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: If you have already installed a nVidia driver be sure to uninstall or purge old driver or else you will have conflicts.

Comment: Please click [edit] and add to your question the release number of Ubuntu you are using. Please do not click Add Comment; use [edit] instead.